# How to modify to every cell in last column in table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify every cell in last column in html table.
My first try is:

```
   $('#example td:last').each(function(elem) {
       //do something with elem
   });
```

But above code modify only last cell in last column (so one cell instead of all cells in column).

How should I change selector to much all `td` in last column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `:last-child` instead of `:last`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('#example tr').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this).find('td:last');
    //do something with elem
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M9GEx/)**

Answer (score 0):

`:last` return a single element, the last element of the jQuery stack. It is exactly the same of doing :

```
var $td = $('#example td');
$td.eq($td.length - 1);
```

What you want is the CSS selector `:last-child`, which return the last child (huh).

```
$('#example td:last-child').each(...);
```